# Resetting the NavGraph after activity recreates

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I've a navigation graph with 2 fragments, Fragment A and Fragment B.
Fragment A is my start destination.

If I'm in Fragment B and I open the app settings, and revoke a permission I see that:

1. activity is recreated, but I don't see `onDestory` is called
2. instead of starting the activity with Fragment A, the activity is started with Fragment B.

I also see that the application is recreated and opens directly Activity B instead of starting from Activity A (old code, we have few activities)

is there a way to reset the navigation graph somehow so it will start from Fragment A?

Thanks.

Comment: On which condition you're willing to reset the navigation graph? For example: when app permission is revoked then fragment A should be loaded.

Comment: Hi @AbdullahJaved, I would like to reset it in when ever the Activity is created (or recreated)

Answer (score 3):

Ran into your question looking for an answer for a similar problem.

In my case, I have a single Activity app which is in Fragment B when the permission state is changed, and also reopens in Fragment B after the Activity is restarted.  Like you, I want my Activity to start with Fragment A, which is also the start or default destination of my nav graph.

The way I solved my problem was that, I would detect whenever the Activity had been *exited* because of a `REASON_PERMISSION_CHANGE`, then I nullify the `savedInstanceState` inside my Activity's `onCreate()`.

Here's some code:

```
// MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(
            when (requiresPermissionChangeRestart()) {
                true -> {
                    Log.e(TAG "Resetting Activity after permissions manual change")
                    null
                }
                false -> {
                    savedInstanceState
                }
            }
        )
    }
...
    private fun requiresPermissionChangeRestart(): Boolean = (getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)
            as ActivityManager).let { am ->
        am.getHistoricalProcessExitReasons(null, 0, 0)
            .find {
                it.reason == ApplicationExitInfo.REASON_PERMISSION_CHANGE
            }
            .run {
                when (this != null) {
                    true -> {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Permissions for package $packageName where changed by the user")
                        true
                    }
                    false -> false
                }
            }
    }

}
```

It might be kind of a hack, but this little trick might help you arrive at a more fitting solution for your particular problem.  As long as you get rid of the `savedInstanceState` from the given Activity when it matters, you should be able to *restart* your Activity the way you would expect it to do so.

Comment: If the reason to skip keeping state of the NavHost is the some init stages (which can be missed on deep fragment wake up) - this is not a hack.

Answer (score 1):

This code will reset nav graph when the activity will recreate.

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    navController.setGraph(R.navigation.your_nav_graph)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing it this way:
in onCreate:

```
savedInstanceState?.let {
        if (!ConfigChange) {
            val fragment: Fragment? =
                supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.my_nav_host)
            fragment.let {
                if (it is NavHostFragment) {
                    it.navController.navigate(R.id.fragmentA)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `ConfigChange` not found. Will you please explain how to get it? Thanks in advance.